# What is causing Wygwam 3.2.2 error: SyntaxError: Parse error, TypeError: Result of expression 'u' [undefined] is not an object

Tags: wygwam

After upgrade of Wygwam on Exp Eng 2.7.2 our module Wygwam 3.2.2 is not loading in the control panel due to the following errors...

SyntaxError: Parse error
/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/skins/wygwam3/skin.js?t=B9VJ5M2

TypeError: Result of expression 'u' [undefined] is not an object.
/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js

There are similar questions here...
[Wygwam3.21 not initializing - ckeditor error: TypeError: u is undefined](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14796/wygwam3-21-not-initializing-ckeditor-error-typeerror-u-is-undefined)
and
[Wygwam - IE8 issue - editor doesn't load and throws javascript error](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17235/wygwam-ie8-issue-editor-doesnt-load-and-throws-javascript-error)

I've deleted and reinstalled the folders in both themes/third_party and module/third_party. Why is it using this particular skin? Any ideas on what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I found the issue I was having. The problem seems to have come from not updating the Channel Images plugin that Wygwam uses to enable inserting of images into the Body field using Channel Images. For some reason I had a different set of errors today compared to yesterday (original errors in my original post) which led me to the Channel Images plugin for ckeditor.